# What is the correct token replacement for action surrounded by [...]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Only for experimental purposes, I want to match `http://localhost:randomport/home/[privacy]/message` as follows.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[[[action]]]/{xxx}")]
    public IActionResult Privacy(string xxx)
    {
        return Content(xxx);
    }
}
```

However, it produces (trimmed) errors:

> Error: While processing template '[controller]/[[[action]]]/{xxx}', a replacement value for the token 'action]' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]' instead.

## Question

What is the correct token replacement for action surrounded by `[...]`?

Comment: I would say that this is a bug in AttributeRouteModel  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ApplicationModels/AttributeRouteModel.cs#L228. You can open an issue about this use case on github.

Comment: @nemesv: Reported. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]/{xxx}")]
        public IActionResult Privacy(string xxx)
        {
            return Content(xxx);
        }
    }
```

A URL such as: localhost:xxxx/Home/Privacy/someString will now work

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't initially. My guess is you originally had one bracket too many on either side. The quotation marks aren't necessary, I've amended my answer.

Comment: It seems I don't know what you want to achieve.

If you want to use brackets in your URL then just use each bracket twice inside the HttpGet(). This makes your URL to look like this: localhost:xxxx/Home/[[NotTheNameOfTheMethodJustSomething]].

However, if you want to write your method name in the URL then use the [action] annotation. This makes your URL look like this: localhost:xxxx/Home/NameOfTheMethod

Comment: I mistakenly posted my comment before I finished it. I'll edit the answer with what I think you most likely need.

Comment: Aaaaaah I finally understood what you want. I've just tried testing it in a couple of ways and nothing seems to work. Sorry.

I am interested though, is there any point behind this exercise? Or is it just to see if you could?